# In Rocket League, how can you complete the Eleven-hundred Points challenge?

Tags: rocket-league

This week, one of the Rocket League weekly challenges is Eleven-hundred Points, which challenges you to score 1,100 points in a single match.  I've seen similar challenges before, and I just don't understand how anyone is expected to complete them.  I've watched ESports pro matches, and the MVP is usually around 400-600 points.

I can think of 2 obvious ways to accomplish it:

1. Collude with the other team to run the score up so everybody can complete the challenge.  Probably easiest in 1v1, since you'd only have to get 1 other person to agree.  I've never tried this.
2. Get matched against a team much worse than you, but who just won't quit.  Normally, the other team will forfeit long before you can accumulate 1,100 points.  I've reached that score in matches vs. bots, but never against actual humans.

Is there some game mode where you have a reasonable chance of getting 1,100 points in a single match?  Why does Rocket League issue this challenge?

**2023 Update:** I've now seen scenario #2 happen, although unfortunately the Eleven-hundred Points challenge was not active at the time.  The MVP in a 3v3 casual soccar match managed 1109 points with 5 goals, 3 assists, 1 save, and 10 shots.  The final score was 9-1.  I only managed 398 points with 2 goals, 2 assists, and 5 shots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a reasonable chance to get 1,100 points if you play [Dropshot](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/dropshot-new-game-mode-march-22/). In Dropshot you have to break floor panels in order to open them up and be able to score goals. After a goal has been scored, the opposing team's field is reset.

To break a panel it has to be hit twice. Each damage you inflict on your opponent's field grants you points (10 per panel). Besides that you can still gain points through Goals, Assists and Saves.

Comment: I tried a few games of Dropshot.  I'm not very good at it, but the MVP was consistently over 1,100 points, and occasionally another player went over as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is 1v1.  Because there are so many more goals than in any other mode, the average points per game tend to be higher than any other mode.

Comment: One problem is I really dislike 1v1.  I find it to be practically a different game.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kagemusha suggests, *Dropshot* is the best mode.

But sometimes there's an even better solution. If a limited mode is active for that week you may want to play [Heatseeker](https://rocketleague.fandom.com/wiki/Heatseeker). In *Heatseeker* the first team to reach 7 goals wins, but each time you hit the ball it will search for the opponent's goal, making very easy to shot. On the other hand, you can do a lot of (epic) saves, ensuring you lots of points.

Comment: True, except if you're as lucky as me and almost always have opponents who destroy/distract you when you're the goalie :(

Comment: @Kagemusha I love that mode, but it attracts too many toxic players, indeed...